# Asset Catalog named colors are not available to @IBInspectable properties

Tags: swift, interface-builder, uicolor, asset-catalog, ibinspectable

For my iPad app that I'm creating, I have an Asset Catalog in my project containing several color sets. I know that I can drag and drop these into the code itself and have done so for the default color of an `@IBInspectable` class property. However, when I go to use these in Interface Builder, my color sets are available to properties like a UIView's background color, but they're not available to any `@IBInspectable` property that allows users to set a color. Is there any way to expose my color sets to my `@IBInspectable` class to where they're selectable in Interface Builder? Sure, I can always set these programmatically, but for future use and convenience's sake, I'd like to get this working if Apple currently supports it. My Colors Asset Catalog is definitely added to my project's Bundle Resources in my Build Settings if that information is relevant.

Screenshots of my issue:

This first image shows where my color sets are selectable for properties like a UIView's background. The next two show where they're not available to my `@IBInspectable` properties.

[image: Color sets selectable for UIView Background]

[image: Color set appears as missing to @IBInspectable property]

[image: Color sets not selectable for @IBInspectable property]

Comment: This is a clear limitation of Xcode and its really annoying. Make sure you submit Feedback to Apple regarding the issue at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Thanks, Nick! This is tracked in radar://33963330, you can reference that bug ID in your own bug reports to help make triage faster. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've found temporary solution till the Xcode resolve this issue.[image]

Please use Recently Used Colors, and if you choose the one that is in your assets (in recent onces) it will automatically change it to the defined one. Works for me :)
[image]

Comment: Great tip. Thanks!